# No output is generated for main function in python TCP server

Tags: python, tcp, server

I wrote a program that would take command line arguments for the host name and port number. It works fine wen I remove the main function and as soon as I define a main function nothing is displayed.

```
import sys
import socket
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
import os
import threading

def Main(serverName,serverPort):
    print('Initialising the socket')
    serverName=sys.argv[1]
    serverPort=int(sys.argv[2])
    serverAddress=(serverName,serverPort)
    #create the TCP/IP socket 
    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect(serverAddress)
    sentence = raw_input('enter string in lower case')
    clientSocket.send(sentence)
    modifiedSentence= clientSocket.recv(1024)
    print ('from Server:'), modifiedSentence
    clientSocket.close()

if __name__==main:
    Main()
```

Comment: Your main function needs two parameters and you're calling it with none of them. Also the starting condition should be `if __name__=='__main__'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main does not run in this case. You need to adjust the if clause, further you need to grab the sys.argv and pass them to the Main() method since you wrote it to require the arguments as inputs.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverName=sys.argv[1]
    serverPort=int(sys.argv[2])
    Main(serverName,serverPort)
```